# DirectoryFieldEditor at dialogs.TitleAreaDialog not validated on key stroke

Tags: eclipse, jface

I do extend `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog` for creating preference dialog. Apart other fields, I create there `org.eclipse.jface.preference.DirectoryFieldEditor`. That one, I would like to validate after every key stroke, so I use `StringFieldEditor.VALIDATE_ON_KEY_STROKE`. But it seems validating only after focus lost, what is default value. `IPropertyChangeListener` is fired only on focus lost (I want to fire it after key stroke), at least validates values correctly. I added `KeyListener`, but `isValid()` is returning incorrect values. Those are fine after focus lost as well.

I have got something similar at `MyPreferencePage extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage`, where I have no problems with validating on key stroke.

As some workaround I tried to use `dirFieldExportPath.load()` inside `KeyListener`, but cursor is moved to the begging after every load (key stroke).

Code:

```java
public class TestDialog extends TitleAreaDialog
{
  // code, fields

  private Viewer               view;
  private String               DialogTitle;
  private String               DialogHeader;
  private Composite            checkboxExportPathParent;
  private Composite            directoryExportPathParent;
  private DirectoryFieldEditor dirFieldExportPath;

  public testDialog(Shell parentShell, Viewer view)
  {
    super(parentShell);
    this.view = view;
  }

  @Override
  protected Control createButtonBar(Composite parent)
  {
    Control buttonBar = super.createButtonBar(parent);
    refreshButtonBarState();
    return buttonBar;
  }

  private void refreshButtonBarState()
  {
    // code
  }

  protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent)
  {
    setTitle(DialogTitle);
    getShell().setText(DialogHeader);

    // code, setting layout

    createHtmlTab();

    return parent;
  }

  private void createHtmlTab()
  {
    TabFolder tabFolder;
    TabItem htmlTabItem = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    htmlTabItem.setText(TabHeader.html3d.getTabHeaderName());

    // insert scroll bar
    final ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(tabFolder, SWT.V_SCROLL);
    sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);// required
    sc.setExpandVertical(true);// required

    htmlTabItem.setControl(sc);

    Composite htmlContainer = new Composite(sc, SWT.None);
    htmlContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));
    htmlContainer.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true));

    sc.setContent(htmlContainer);

    // Export path

    checkboxExportPathParent = new Composite(htmlContainer, SWT.NONE);
    checkboxExportPathParent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, false);
    checkboxExportPathParent.setLayoutData(gridData);

    directoryExportPathParent = new Composite(htmlContainer, SWT.NONE);
    directoryExportPathParent.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL));

    dirFieldExportPath = new DirectoryFieldEditor(ExportPathStr, ExportPathStr, directoryExportPathParent);
    dirFieldExportPath.setEnabled(enabled);
    // dirFieldExportPath.setPreferenceStore(Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
    dirFieldExportPath.setEmptyStringAllowed(!enabled);
    dirFieldExportPath.setValidateStrategy(StringFieldEditor.VALIDATE_ON_KEY_STROKE);
    dirFieldExportPath.setPreferenceName(PreferenceConstants.P_HTMLEXPORTPATH);

    String exportPath = ps.getString(PreferenceConstants.P_HTMLEXPORTPATH);
    if (exportPath != null && !exportPath.isEmpty())
      dirFieldExportPath.setStringValue(exportPath);

    if (!dirFieldExportPath.isValid())
      this.setErrorMessage("not valid");
    else
      this.setErrorMessage("valid");/**/

    dirFieldExportPath.getTextControl(directoryExportPathParent).addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
      {
        String eP = dirFieldExportPath.getStringValue();
        System.out.println("ExportAndPrintDialog.createHtmlTab()>keyReleased>eP:" + eP);
        Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().setValue(PreferenceConstants.P_HTMLEXPORTPATH, eP);
        // dirFieldExportPath.setPreferenceStore(Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
        // dirFieldExportPath.load();
      }

      @Override
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }
    });

    dirFieldExportPath.setPropertyChangeListener(new IPropertyChangeListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event)
      {
        System.out.println("ExportAndPrintDialog.createHtmlTab()>propertyChange>isValid:" + dirFieldExportPath.isValid());
        // code
      }
    });

    // required; set after all composites were added;
    sc.setMinSize(htmlContainer.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
  }

}
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Well all xxxFieldEditor classes expect to be part of a FieldEditorPreferencePage and won't work properly elsewhere unless you reproduce the setup the preference page does. From a quick look the `getTextControl` method looks like it sets up the key listener.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449! I think I have got the solution. It has be tested a bit more before I can post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I came with the workaround, it seems to work as desired. I created custom `DirectoryFieldEditor` to have access to `protected boolean checkState()`. There I want also expand env. variables. Then after every `ModifyEvent` runs validation. I added the same logic to custom `FileFieldEditor`.

created new class:

```
public class DialogDirectoryFieldEditor extends DirectoryFieldEditor
{
  //private boolean isValid;

  public DialogDirectoryFieldEditor()
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  public DialogDirectoryFieldEditor(String name, String labelText, Composite parent)
  {
    super(name, labelText, parent);
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean doCheckState()
  {
    String fileName = getTextControl().getText();
    fileName = fileName.trim();
    if (fileName.length() == 0 && isEmptyStringAllowed())
      return true;
    if (fileName.length() == 0)
      return false;

    File file = new File(expandEnvironmentVariables(fileName));
    return file.isDirectory();
  }
}
```

and in `TestDialog`:

```
dirFieldExportPath = new DialogDirectoryFieldEditor(ExportPathStr, ExportPathStr, directoryExportPathParent);
dirFieldExportPath.setEnabled(ps.getBoolean(PreferenceConstants.P_HTML_USE_EXPORTPATH), directoryExportPathParent);
dirFieldExportPath.setEmptyStringAllowed(!ps.getBoolean(PreferenceConstants.P_HTML_USE_EXPORTPATH));
dirFieldExportPath.setPreferenceName(PreferenceConstants.P_HTMLEXPORTPATH);

String exportPath = ps.getString(PreferenceConstants.P_HTMLEXPORTPATH);
if (exportPath != null && !exportPath.isEmpty())
  dirFieldExportPath.setStringValue(exportPath);

// validate path after any input change
dirFieldExportPath.getTextControl(directoryExportPathParent).addModifyListener(new ModifyListener()
{
  @Override
  public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e)
  {
    ps.setValue(
        PreferenceConstants.P_HTMLEXPORTPATH, dirFieldExportPath.getStringValue());
    refreshButtonBarState();
  }
});

private void refreshButtonBarState() {
  // other code
  
    if (htmlTabSelected())
      String errorMessage = refreshValidState();
      
}

private String refreshValidState()
{
  if (htmlTabSelected())
  {
    if (dirFieldExportPath != null)
    {
      boolean dirFieldExportPathValid = 
          Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().getBoolean(PreferenceConstants.P_HTML_USE_EXPORTPATH) 
          ? dirFieldExportPath.doCheckState() : true;
      if (!dirFieldExportPathValid)
        return ExportPathStr + " " + dirFieldNotValid;
    }
    
    return null;// no error message displayed
  }
  return "";
}
```